# Performance of FS directory structures

Tags: filesystems, database

Given a large (hundreds of thousands objects) fs-based database of uniquely identified objects with potentially a large number of long prefixes with many objects sharing the same prefix are treeish structures preferred over a single flat directory on common Unix/Linux filesystems?

Are there any benchmarks on this?

Comment: many filesystems have abysmal performance when a directory has many thousands of files/subdirs in it.  it's not uncommon to use some kind of algorithm to distribute files to one of, say, 26 (e.g. alpha sorted by first letter) or 100 or 256 (e.g. a one-way hash from filename to 1-100 or 1-256) subdirectories based on the filename.  ext2 was bad, ext3/4 greatly improved performance in that situation. xfs was good, as was reiserfs.  don't know of any benchmarks, offhand.

Comment: BTW, some hashing methods used two levels of subdirs, e.g. from `./00/00/filename` to `./ff/ff/filename`...IIIRC that's what `squid` does for it's object cache.  ah, not quite.  `squid` uses `/var/spool/squid/00/00/` to `/var/spool/squid/0F/FF/` or 16 subdirectories with 256 subdirectories each by default.